# Transaction records?

Tags: transactions

Can you track your payment if you do a transaction from person to person for a house rental if the seller doesn't follow through with their end of the deal and doesn't send the keys can you get your money back?

Or in other words is there a record of your transaction so you can claim a dispute or track down the person who didn't follow through?

What safety do i have in this aspect for example i am applying for  rental house but i found out they're in the states and I'm in Canada so they have to send me they keys but they want the payment first through btc wallet so if i do this and send the bitcoins and he doesn't send me the keys and i find out it was a scam is there a way for me to recover my payment?

Comment: You have no safety. If the seller doesn't follow through, your money is gone forever. no-one can get it back for you. There is no way to recover payment. There is no way to identify or trace the seller.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you track your payment if you do a transaction from person to person for a house rental if the seller doesn't follow through with their end of the deal and doesn't send the keys can you get your money back?

You can view your transaction's status on a block explorer or your own node, if yu have one. You cannot get the money back unless the other party explicitly sends it back to you in a new transaction. Bitcoin transactions are irreversible once confirmed.

> Or in other words is there a record of your transaction so you can claim a dispute or track down the person who didn't follow through?

Bitcoin is a decentralized system. There is no one to file a dispute with.

> What safety do i have in this aspect for example i am applying for rental house but i found out they're in the states and I'm in Canada so they have to send me they keys but they want the payment first through btc wallet so if i do this and send the bitcoins and he doesn't send me the keys and i find out it was a scam is there a way for me to recover my payment?

Usually, for such transactions, you would utilize an escrow service that only releases the BTC to the seller after you have received what you paid for. You should ask the seller to use a reputable BTC escrow (there are a few on Bitcointalk). If the seller refuses, you should proceed with caution, if at all, as many people are scammed by such offers.